# Stackoverflow exception (0xc00000fd) in Windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have developed a windows service .exe having multiple services in it like below:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        {
            new Service1(),
            new Service2(),
            new Service3(),
            new Service4()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

I am getting following fatal error (checking event logs) on production which is **stackoverflow** exception:

Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x522e8317

Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18047, time stamp: 0x58dcff99

Exception code: 0xc00000fd

Fault offset: 0x004226a2

Faulting process id: 0xeb4c

Faulting application start time: 0x01d2a9de37398bdb

Faulting application path: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyApp.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

Report Id: d52424aa-1a16-11e3-bc4b-002590a4ec55

Below is the code for one of my windows service :

```
private Timer timer1 = null;
private static object _intervalSync = new object(); 

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(900000); // 15mins
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {       
        if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(_intervalSync))
        {
            try
            {
               // execute code
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogException(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_intervalSync);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Please find the recursive code:

```
public void fetchInventorySupplyFromAmazon(Parameter parameter, DateTime queryStartDateTime)
    {
        ListInventorySupplyResponse listInventorySupplyResponse = new ListInventorySupplyResponse();
        ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse = new ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse();
        FBAInventoryDetailServiceMWS fbaInventoryDetailServiceMWS = new FBAInventoryDetailServiceMWS(parameter);
        SetParameter setParameter = new SetParameter();
        try
        {
            if (parameter.nextToken != null && parameter.nextToken != "")
            {

                listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse = fbaInventoryDetailServiceMWS.InvokeListInventorySupplyByNextToken(parameter.nextToken);
                foreach (var inventorySupply in listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse.ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResult.InventorySupplyList.member)
                {
                    insertUpdateInventory(inventorySupply, parameter);
                }
                if (listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse.IsSetListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResult())
                {
                    setParameter.SetParameterValue(parameter, listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse.ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResult.NextToken);
                //recursive call
                    fetchInventorySupplyFromAmazon(parameter, queryStartDateTime);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                listInventorySupplyResponse = fbaInventoryDetailServiceMWS.InvokeListInventorySupply(queryStartDateTime);
                foreach (var inventorySupply in listInventorySupplyResponse.ListInventorySupplyResult.InventorySupplyList.member)
                {
                    insertUpdateInventory(inventorySupply, parameter);
                }
                if (listInventorySupplyResponse.ListInventorySupplyResult.NextToken != null && listInventorySupplyResponse.ListInventorySupplyResult.NextToken != "")
                {
                    setParameter.SetParameterValue(parameter, listInventorySupplyResponse.ListInventorySupplyResult.NextToken);
                //recursive call
                    fetchInventorySupplyFromAmazon(parameter, queryStartDateTime);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersException ex)
        {
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.ErrorCode) ? ex.ErrorCode.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals("NEXTTOKENCORRUPTED") : false) ||
                ex.StatusCode.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals("UNAUTHORIZED"))
            {
                setParameter.SetParameterValue(parameter, null);
                //recursive call
                fetchInventorySupplyFromAmazon(parameter, queryStartDateTime);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Any Help would be great !!

Comment: You have nothing in the // execute code bit?

Comment: @john it's my business logic which fetches data from web api and dumps it into database

Comment: Well, a stack overflow means that the trace stack runs out of space. Do you have any methods calling themselves (perhaps via a second method) in an uncontrolled (or overly deep) way? The code you've shown us does not appear to be problematic, so I assume there's a problem in your business logic.

Comment: yeah i have a recursive function which fetches data from web api. Let me post it

Comment: @john I have updated the post. Please check **fetchInventorySupplyFromAmazon** recursive function. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you updating "nextToken" on the parameter object? I see you calling "SetParameterValue", but I don't know if this is being set. Either way, I suspect NextToken _is not_ being updated and therefore continually requesting the same page.

This isn't the best way to do paging, anyway, since you could still hit the stack limit even without a bug in your code, if you had enough pages. For all I know, this is what's happening here. It's better to page in a loop (i.e. `nextToken = null; do { } while (!string.IsNullorEmpty(nextToken));`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my business logic.
I have changed the **fetchInventorySupplyFromAmazon** function to include **do while loop** instead of recursive calls.

```
 public void fetchInventorySupplyFromAmazon(Parameter parameter, DateTime queryStartDateTime)
    {
        ListInventorySupplyResponse listInventorySupplyResponse = new ListInventorySupplyResponse();
        ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse = new ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse();
        FBAInventoryDetailServiceMWS fbaInventoryDetailServiceMWS = new FBAInventoryDetailServiceMWS(parameter);
        SetParameter setParameter = new SetParameter();

        try
        {
            parameter.nextToken = null;
            do
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.nextToken))
                {
                    listInventorySupplyResponse = fbaInventoryDetailServiceMWS.InvokeListInventorySupply(queryStartDateTime);
                    if (listInventorySupplyResponse.ListInventorySupplyResult != null)
                    {
                        if (listInventorySupplyResponse.ListInventorySupplyResult.InventorySupplyList != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var inventorySupply in listInventorySupplyResponse.ListInventorySupplyResult.InventorySupplyList.member)
                            {
                                insertUpdateInventory(inventorySupply, parameter);
                            }
                        }

                        setParameter.SetParameterValue(parameter, listInventorySupplyResponse.ListInventorySupplyResult.NextToken);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse = fbaInventoryDetailServiceMWS.InvokeListInventorySupplyByNextToken(parameter.nextToken);
                    if (listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse.ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResult != null)
                    {
                        if (listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse.ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResult.InventorySupplyList != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var inventorySupply in listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse.ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResult.InventorySupplyList.member)
                            {
                                insertUpdateInventory(inventorySupply, parameter);
                            }
                        }
                        setParameter.SetParameterValue(parameter, listInventorySupplyByNextTokenResponse.ListInventorySupplyByNextTokenResult.NextToken);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        setParameter.SetParameterValue(parameter, null);
                    }
                }
            } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.nextToken));

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```